# Cannot find the declaration of element 'bookstore'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I am a beginner for XMl and XSD.I have developed XML and XSD file.I used [Liquid](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator) online xml validater to validate my XML file against my XSD.When I try to to validate my XML I got error "cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'bookstore'.". How can I fix this issue?

This is my XML

```
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books">
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <p>
      <price>10</price>
      <price>10</price>
      <price>20</price>
    </p>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

This is XSD

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://www.contoso.com/books" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="bookstore">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="book">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="author">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="first-name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="last-name" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="p">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
                                        <xs:element name="price1" type="xs:decimal" />
                                        <xs:element name="price2" type="xs:decimal" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:assert test="price = price1 + price2"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="genre" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="publicationdate" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="ISBN" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the way you are invoking the schema validator (which you haven't told us about)